# jquery background image styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble styling a background image that I'm using jQuery to cycle the source of. The image is inserted in the css as a background and stretched to cover the entire window. Here's my css:

```
html {
    background: url(images/image_1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Before adding the jQuery swapper the image looks as intended. When I add the swapper, however, the css styling fails. The cover effects seem to drop and I'm left with a fixed-size image. The swapping works perfectly, though. I would think the jQuery css would add to to css but it's almost as if it's overriding all the properties for the html element and just leaving me with the background source but no covering. Here's what my html and javascript look like:

```
<html>

<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script language="javascript">
<!--
    var ctr = 0;

    $(document).ready( function () {
        nextBg();
    });

    function nextBg()
    {
        ++ctr;

        if( ctr <= 3 )
        {
            $("html").css( "background", "url(images/repurpose2/image_" + ctr + ".jpg) no-repeat center center fixed" );
            if( ctr == 3 )
                ctr = 0;
        }
    }
//-->
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=style.css>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="image-swapper">
        <a href="#" onclick="nextBg();" />Next</a>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm using the background image swapping approach I found here:
[Loop thru 100 background-images onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513602/loop-thru-100-background-images-onclick)

Can anyone tell me why I am unable to style my html with the style.css file?

Thanks very much!

Comment: fiddle please? or a link?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your Javascript console? Better yet, can you make a fiddle showing this behavour?

Comment: Thanks you two for taking the time to respond. I was just putting a link together when I noticed the answers below that have solved the problem. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trampling on all `background` properties just to update the url. `background` like `border` and `margin` is a shorthand rule for combining various specific rules and does not need to be used at all and in this case it should be avoided, since you're only wanting to update one of the more specific rules, `background-image`.

Just swap out:

```
 $("html").css( "background", "url(images/repurpose2/image_" + ctr + ".jpg) no-repeat center center fixed" );
```

with

```
 $("html").css( "background-image", "url(images/repurpose2/image_" + ctr + ".jpg)");
```

Comment: Nice! I have batting at flies all day missing some quirk of a library or another. Nice animation, btw.

Comment: Animation?   I finished putting the page together - here's what it turned out like - http://www.seanoneill.us/test/project-repurpose.html. I have very little idea of what I'm doing - just learning all this html/css/jsish stuff for the first time while putting this little online portfolio of architecture work together - so it's pretty amateur. Super stoked about getting the javascript to work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript">
    var ctr = 0;

    $(document).ready( function () {
        nextBg();
    });

    function nextBg()
    {   
        ++ctr;
        if( ctr <= 3 )
        {
            imageUrl = "images/repurpose2/image_" + ctr + ".jpg";
            $('html').css('background-image', 'url("' + imageUrl + '")');
            $('html').css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
            $('html').css('background-position', 'center');
            $('html').css('background-attachment', 'fixed');
            if( ctr == 3 )
            {
                ctr = 0;
            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Ankit. Thanks for taking the time to offer this. The suggestion below provided an instafix with the "background-image" switch. I have to admit I don't really know what I'm doing - does what you've got here improve on the method I was using + the fix below? Thanks again!